# why this code is not showing correct result ,however i change the value of the text box initial the result will still be 32 as if y=0

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let y = document.getElementById("weathMeas").innerHTML;

function calc(y) {
  var z;
  z = (y * 1.8) + 32;
  return z;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calc(y);
```

```html
<head>
  <section id="calcBody"> <span id="infomsg">Please enter current temperature :</span>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="weathMeas" name="weather" value="58">
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="result" value="result!">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </section>
</head>
```

Comment: `getElementById("weathMeas")` is an input and has a value, not innerHTML. You also have no event handlers setup

Comment: You only call the function once, when the page first loads. You don't call it again when the input is changed.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's why i gave the value to the initial code ,i dont want to call the function one more time ,i only need it to work once

Comment: @j08691 the code is simple i think you already got the idea ,i need an inital value of 58 celsius to be converted to fahrenheit , so what should the right code look like

Comment: Just change `document.getElementById("weathMeas").innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("weathMeas").value`

Comment: shouldn't the function run everytime you press the result button instead of just once?

Comment: @MahmoudFarid `let y = document.getElementById("weathMeas").value;`. But this only works once, when the page loads. You need to setup an event listener for it to work whenever you change the input

Comment: @ChrisG i forgot the button piece of code ,my bad ,it is only a trial code and by the way how can i make the code call the function every time i hit the button because i was also struggling a bit with that

Comment: @MahmoudFarid add a `onclick="yourfunctionname()"` to your button. This will call the function everytime you press it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
function calc() {
  let y = document.getElementById("weathMeas").value;
  let yInt = parseInt(y);
  
  var z;
  z = (yInt * 1.8) + 32;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <section id="calcBody"> <span id="infomsg">Please enter current temperature :</span>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="weathMeas" name="weather" value="58">
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="result" value="result!" onclick="calc()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </section>
</head>
```